# angular data binding in radio buttons

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angular js and I have some things need to be clear about angular js.
Here is my sample code

```
<body ng-app="radioExample">
   <script>
   angular.module('radioExample', [])
     .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.color = 'blue';
       $scope.disabled = false;

       if($scope.color == 'red'){
         $scope.disabled = true;
       }

     }]);
 </script>
 <form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
   <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="red" >  Red <br/>
   <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="green"> Green <br/>
   <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="blue"> Blue <br/>
   <tt>color = {{color | json}}</tt><br/>
   <tt>{{disabled}}</tt><br/>
  </form>

</body>
```

when I select the "Red" button, doesn't it update the value of `$scope.disabled` into `true` as I mentioned in `if` statement? when I need to do it, how can I achieve it?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No it won't, you can try something like** using ng-change listener and assigning the scope

```
 <body ng-app="radioExample">
   <script>
      angular.module('radioExample', [])
        .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
          $scope.color = 'blue';
          $scope.disabled = false;

          $scope.foo = function(){
            if ($scope.color === 'red'){
            $scope.disabled = true;
          }
      }
        }]);
   </script>
   <form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
      <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="red" ng-change="foo()" >  Red <br/>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="green" ng-change="foo()"> Green <br/>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="blue" ng-change="foo()"> Blue <br/>
      <tt>color = {{color | json}}</tt><br/>
      <tt>{{disabled}}</tt><br/>
   </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1

Simple solution would be to Define disabled as function so that angular recomputes in each digest cycle.

```
$scope.disabled = function() { return $scope.color === 'red'; }
```

Later use

```
<tt>{{disabled()}}</tt>
```

## Solution 2

If you don't want `disabled` to be a function. Add a watch on `color` and update value of disabled.

```
$scope.$watch('color', function(){
  $scope.disabled = ($scope.color === 'red');
})
```